# Building CQL in NDepend for verifying MVVM patterns

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm, ndepend, cql, cqlinq

I wanted to verify few design patterns in C# code by static analysis. I want to verify these using NDepend. The application is built with MVVM design style, so typical design patterns that I would like to verify are:
    1. View-Model classes do not have any DependencyProperties (WPF elements), they should only be seen in View layer.
    2. The View layer should not implement IDisposable etc

I have tried building queries in CQL to capture these details, but failed as I need to verify which level a class belongs to and also the properties of it. I understand nested query is not supported by CQL yet, so is there any way I can capture these details by NDepend? I am hoping I can somehow capture the results of multiple queries and perform intersection of them?

Thanks in advance,
Shaun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get a [CQLinq rule](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#CQL) that warns if A is using B (A and B can be *Assembly/ Namespace/ Type/ Method/ Field*) is to view A and B in the Dependency Matrix, and to **Generate a code rule that warns if this dependency exists**:

[image: Generate a code rule that warns if this dependency exists]

...and as a result, the following rule is generated:

[image: Code rule genetaed]

Comment: Thanks Patrick for the reply. I have tried doing this, but this is not exactly what I want. I would like to have a CQL query to verify if a DependencyPattern belongs to a particular set of classes (e.g. classes belonging to the View layer). So I have to check two things in the same query: 1) if the class belongs to a particular layer and 2) if the Dependency property exists. Can I do this in CQL?

Comment: Could it be: WARN IF Count > 0 IN SELECT TYPES FROM "xxx" WHERE IsDirectlyUsedBy "yyy" OR IsDirectlyUsingBy "zzz"

Comment: Thanks Patrick.
It gave me an error. I think only Assemblies and namespaces are expected after FROM keyword.

Comment: If some asm and namespace have the same name prefix them like:   FROM "ASSEMBLY:XXX"  or FROM "NAMESPACE:XXX"